# Incorporating more information from comments while editing

Tags: discussion, editing, comments

Editing guidelines (for example [this meta question](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/1318/editing-others-posts-guidelines-etiquette)) do not give any information about incorporating additional information from comments.

For example, while editing [this](https://superuser.com/questions/85948/how-can-i-embed-programming-source-code-in-powerpoint-slide-and-keep-code-highlig), there is additional rather important information in comments:

> I use textmate, e-texteditor and eclipse the most.

1. While making other changes (worth of editing), should I format that additional information from comments back to question, especially when person who asked the question wrote the comment?
2. In more complicated case (longer comment thread, or additional (important) information in comments of answers), is just copying information back to question worth of editing?

In my opinion questions are much better if you don't have to read comments to know important details. Same reasoning goes for my answers; usually I edit proposed improvements from comments to answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Feel free to add the additional information to the post, I normally 'soft guide' users to do this by leaving them a comment. However, many new users fail to understand this concept.

As long as you think you improved the quality of the post, nobody should have problems with your edit. Especially since better posts tend to get more votes, you're only doing them a favor :-)

Answer (score 5):

I find that comments tend to point out major omissions and other oversights that really deserve to be edited into / fixed in the post.

So I agree, but I would only **fold in the most significant feedback from the comments** -- don't feel obliged to make tiny changes for every single comment on the post.